# All Elements click trigger not firing

Tags: google-tag-manager

After having configured hundreds of websites in GTM, I'm coming across a basic issue with Google Tag Manager which I have no clue solving.

I have configured a trigger "Click - All Elements" which should fire on all clicks (so no additional rules defined). However, it's not recording any of my clicks in the preview pane of GTM. Typically, it shows a new event every time I click on any component.

Because of this issue, I cannot trigger any tags that rely on any GTM click triggers.

I already tried linking it to a basic tag to see if anything happens, but nothing, obviously...

I somehow feel that the gtm.click event is being blocked by some other script on the website, but I have no clue on how to go about this.

Any clues on where to look first to try boiling this down to the root cause? Or, alternatively, might there be a way to configure a tag that forces the gtm.click listener to activate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to track the issue down

The below addEventListener caused my GTM pageview event not to load, blocking click event triggers:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
// xxx
}];
})
```